# MariaDB: Insert fails due to random Unicode codepoint

Tags: mysql, unicode, mariadb, utf8mb4

I’m using MariaDB 10.6.16, but reproduced the same behaviour with 10.3.39, too. My problem is this little SQL snippet:

```sql
CREATE TABLE problem (
    text   TEXT
) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO problem (text) VALUES ('');
```

This results in the error message:

```
ERROR 1366 (22007) at line 5: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\xA4\x8B\xAE' for column `problem`.`text` at row 1
```

The bytes `\xF0\xA4\x8B\xAE` represent the character  exactly, so the problem is that MariaDB doesn’t allow inserting this specific character.

What I’ve tried:

- checking the character. It’s [U+242EE](https://codepoints.net/U+242EE), an ancient Unicode character defined in 2001. So it shouldn’t be a problem with too new a code point for the collation.
- checking two MariaDB versions, as noted above.
- removing the collation and charset from the table definition. No change.
- using other 4 byte characters in the SQL query. They work just fine, it’s only this (and possibly some other random CJK characters, too).

How can I convince MariaDB to insert this character into my DB?

Comment: Since you mentioned, that other characters are working fine - that rules out Client  Connection encoding issue (so it must be using UTF-8).

Can you just double check `SHOW CREATE TABLE problem` and see that encoding you specified is actually there ?

Also can we see `character_set_server` and `collation_server` variables ?

Comment: Why collation_server? It is a server variable which specifies sort order and other things but is totally ignored on clientside.

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/S_sSwsZa) seems to manage. Use [set names](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-names/) it make it easier to get them all right.

Comment: Thank you, @danblack! Prepending a `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';` seems to actually fix my problem. (Could you add an answer so that I can accept it?) Thanks, @TyagiAkhilesh and @GeorgRichter, too! (The `*_server` variables were indeed set to `latin1` and `latin1_swedish_ci`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the consistent character set for `CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS`, `CHARACTER_SET_CONNECTION` and `CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT` is required to use non-default character sets.

To do this all in one statement, use `SET NAMES`, in this case:

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4
```

Will set all these client related system variables to a character set that supports the '' character.

The collation is automaticity set to the default for the character set, though it can be explicit with [set names](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-names/) too.